# When I paste a long string into a certain Batch file it only pastes part of it

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste

I have a Decryption file and an Encryption file. When I paste a string into the encryption file, it works perfectly and encrypts it into numbers. But when I try to paste the encrypted string into the decryption program (via RightClick, paste), it only pastes around a quarter of the string into the file, and for some reason, executes from there as if I had clicked the enter button. Here is the code for the Decryption file:

```
  @echo off
title Decryptor
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set /p inputcode=Code:
set /p code=Text:
set chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

for /L %%N in (10 1 36) do (

for /F %%C in ("!chars:~%%N,1!") do (

set /a MATH=%%N*%inputcode%

for /F %%F in ("!MATH!") do (
set "code=!code:%%F=%%C!"
)
)
)

for /f %%F in ("!code!") do (

set "code=!code:-=!"

)

echo !code!
echo Press a key to exit!
pause >NUL
exit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha it turns out I'm just very stupid, and has my string split onto separate lines. When I joined it all together it works perfectly. Problem solved.
Apologies to anyone who read that paragraph of text and long piece of code ;).